# Which flags have value -1 when all selected and which ones don't?

Tags: azerothcore, trinitycore

In AzerothCore/TrinityCore DB some flags (bitmask values) have resulting value `-1` when all bits are enabled, while other flags don't.

Is there a list of such flags so I can distinguish the 2 groups?

For example [creature.spawnMask](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature#spawnmask) does NOT have `-1` when all flags selected.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Shauren on Discord:

> to be able to insert -1 to database, it means the field must be signed
> which gets super annoying when you actually have a flag that occupies
> the highest bit so answering the original question no field. its a bug
> if it works

It looks like no flags should have value `-1` when all bits selected.